# What is the creator/company of this small plug type?

Tags: identification, connector

I bought a https://www.supermicro.com/de/products/motherboard/x13sav-lvds
and would like to know who is the originator/company of the small 4-pin plug beside the 8-pin EPS plug which is used to power on/power off the mainboard.

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mtPG.png)

Here you can see the view on top of the plug:

[image]

And here the plug itself:

[image: plug].

It is not Molex Micro/Mini Fit. I already bought such plugs and they are not compatible.

Answer (score 5):

Can't give a definitive answer without contact mating pitch and housing dimensions, but the insulation between the cavities is distinctive enough that I'd say it's a Samtec Mini Mate IPL1.  The socket part number is IPL1-102-02-S-D-K-TR or its through-hole equivalent.

Comment: Confirmed: [male](https://www.samtec.com/products/ipl1) and [female](https://www.samtec.com/products/ipd1).